# Is it possible to set the height of a Tableau dashboard equal to zero using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tableau-api

I'm creating a website where I'm displaying data visualizations from Tableau Public. I'm embedding them using the HTML embed script. I'd like the dashboards to be hidden when the website loads at first and add a toggle button that shows the dashboard and collapses it. I was trying to achieve this by setting the height of the tableauPlaceholder to 0 `.tableauPlaceholder { height: 0; }` and then adding a class to it that sets the height to a fixed value, like this: `.show-dashboard { height: 20rem }` and give the button the functionality to toggle this class using JavaScript.

This approach didn't work because the Tableau graphic keeps showing even if the height is 0 . So, I'm wondering if it's even possible to set the height of a tableau embed to 0? Is there another approach to achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you combine `height: 0` with `overflow: hidden`? `height: 0` does not move the conent out of flow. As such it will still show the content and overflow the container unless you declare `overflow: hidden`

Comment: Can you link to a publicly-accessible example of a Tableau dashboard in a web-page?

Comment: Better idea: wrap the Tableau widget in a `<details><summary>` structure, then you can toggle it on-and-off without any JavaScript or needing to set any explicit height value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Comment: Why not toggle `display` or `visibility` attribute values instead of messing about with the `height`...?